# Array error how to make it work?

Tags: javascript

```
var facebook_info = [{name:"",url:""}];

for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * friend_list[0].fql_result_set.length);   
    facebook_info[i].name=friend_list[0].fql_result_set[randomNum].name;
    facebook_info[i].url=friend_list[0].fql_result_set[randomNum].pic_square_with_logo;     

    console.log(facebook_info.name[i]);
    console.log(facebook_info.url[i]);
}
```

I am trying to put two inputs to array but it occurs error when I compile it.
I think the way I declare array is wrong.
Any solution for that?
Thank you.

Comment: { stack: [Getter/Setter],
  arguments: [ 'name', undefined ],
  type: 'non_object_property_store',
  message: [Getter/Setter] }
TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var facebook_info = [{name:"",url:""}];
```

creates an Array with one element. Instead, you should create an empty Array like this:

```
var facebook_info = [];
```

Then, push things into `facebook_info` in your loop, like this:

```
for (...) {
  ...
  var random_friend = friend_list[0].fql_result_set[randomNum];
  facebook_info.push({
    name: random_friend.name,
    url: random_friend.pic_square_with_logo
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have one element in the array facebook_info, and yet you are trying to iterate over the array for 10 elements.

Try this instead:

```
var facebook_info = [];

for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * friend_list[0].fql_result_set.length);   
    var name=friend_list[0].fql_result_set[randomNum].name;
    var url=friend_list[0].fql_result_set[randomNum].pic_square_with_logo;     
        facebook_info.push({
            "name":name,
            "url":url
        });

    console.log(facebook_info.name[i]);
    console.log(facebook_info.url[i]);
}
```

Comment: I want to add only 10 inputs to facebook_info.That's why I set i equal to 10.

Comment: You have global variable `i` also you have several `var`s inside loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

Please note that you have global variable `i` in your code, and second thing how you compile JavaScript?

```
var facebook_info = [],
    len =  facebook_info.length,
    i,
    randomNum;

for(i=0; i<len; i++){
    randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * friend_list[0].fql_result_set.length);

    facebook_info[i] = {name: friend_list[0].fql_result_set[randomNum].name, url: friend_list[0].fql_result_set[randomNum].pic_square_with_logo};

}
```